# Change the domain name pointing in Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace

I need advice about my website which is hosted in Google Apps (free plan).

Currently I use a domain name called "A" and have already added another domain name called "A+" as a secondary domain in my Google Apps account.  I set my email accounts with this "A" and "A+" domain name.

How do I set the domain name "A" so when my web visitor accesses it, it will automatically forward to the "A+" website? Will my emails still work properly without any problem?

Answer (score 1):

Forwarding users wouldn't be set up in Google Apps unless your domain is *registered* with Google. Your best option to achieve this is with a redirect. You could set this up by:

1. Going into your domain registrar's control panel and setting it to redirect all traffic from one domain to the other
2. Adding a rewrite rule (in Apache this would be in your .htaccess file) to 301 redirect all traffic from one domain to the other.

If you can point both domains to your current hosting then the .htaccess rewrite is probably your better option. YMMV but it may look something like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^.old-domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} www.old-domain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^new-domain.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can also visit [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redirects) for a bit more guidance on that front.